# apache rewrite don't redirect?

Tags: mod-rewrite

apache .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^promotion\.php\?do=content&id=38&mail$ promotion\.php?lang=tc&do=content&id=38 [R,L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: is your `RewriteEngine` is on?

Comment: Post the URL you expected to be rewritten.

Comment: @Nemoden yes, RewriteEngine is on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the query string, you have to use %{QUERY_STRING} like shown below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^do=content&id=38&mail$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^promotion\.php$ promotion.php?lang=tc&do=content&id=38 [R,L]
```

Put it in the folder where promotion.php is present. I'm not sure how to involve `RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST}` above.